# Python ignore stdout after it once hit 100

Tags: python, stdout

I am starting a subprocess via python and display the stdout (progress) in a Progress bar:

```
def rv(args):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["linkto.exe"]+[x for x in args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if line != "":
            progressStr=re.search(r"([0-9]+.[0-9]+%)", line.rstrip())
            if progressStr == None:
                print line.rstrip()
            else:
                progressInt=int(float(re.sub("[^0123456789\.]", "", progressStr.group())))
                print progressInt
        else:
            break
```

As you see, progressInt is my cleaned up version of the stdout with integer values for the progress % - it works fine so far. However, depending on my input the stdout may vary because the subprocess may spawn another process after the primary one.
How could I drop all lines of my stdout after progressInt hits 100 for the first time?

Comment: You cannot have two else's also use `if progressStr is None:` and `if line `

Comment: I messed up the indentations in the code display - the latest edit shows the proper version.

Comment: do you want to kill the process when you reach 100?

Comment: also `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,"")` will replace your while

Comment: why not just  `if progressInt > 100:break`?

Comment: ah, thank you, I will change it accordingly. I dont want to kill the process after line 100, the processInt should just stop being fed by stdout after it hits 100. At the moment it starts at 1 again when the second process is executed, which is what I'd like to avoid.

If progressInt > 100:break will not work since it starts over at 1 again.

Comment: how will you break if you redirect stdout though?

Comment: that is a good qestion, maybe break isnt the answer then.
I managed to get the desired behaviour now using another re.search to clean the stdout before progressStr and progressInt are being referenced. Thank you for your input Padraic!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution via re.search. There was a small difference in the stdout of process1 (writes "Info:") and process2 (writes "Info [32]:").

```
def rv(args):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/Tweak/RV-4.2.3-64/bin/rvio_hw.exe"]+[x for x in args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
        noFFMpeg=re.search(r"INFO: (.*)", line.rstrip())
        if noFFMpeg is not None:
            progressStr=re.search(r"([0-9]+.[0-9]+%)", noFFMpeg.group())
            if progressStr is not None:
                progressInt=int(float(re.sub("[^0123456789\.]", "", progressStr.group())))
                self.prog_QProgressBar.setValue(progressInt)
                QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
                print progressStr.group()
```

Comment: You  don't need   `if line is not "" ` or `line = p.stdout.readline()`   that is what the for loop does. Also you can remove the last else break

Comment: no worries, the last arg to iter is basically when to loop until so line will never be `""`

Comment: one last thing replace the else with  `if noFFMpeg is not None:` and you can remove `if noFFMpeg is None:` same with `if progressStr is None`

Comment: that makes perfect sense